# How to avoid `go get` `unknown revision` problem which occurs only inside Docker?

Tags: git, docker, go

When I follow an exact sequence of steps of cloning and building my project outside of docker it works well. When I place the exact same sequence into a docker file I am seeing the following error.

I don't know enough about docker to know how to formulate this question more succinctly, except to say, does anyone know how to resolve this type of error.

```
Step 18/22 : RUN go build
 ---> Running in 27e0719b2e7d
go: gitlab.com/myorg/lalo@v0.12.3: reading gitlab.com/myorg/lalo/go.mod at revision v0.12.3: unknown revision v0.12.3
```

To be clear, I am able to create a new empty temporary folder on my computer (without docker and do a full clean build), it is only when I do the same in docker that I see this unknown revision issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the following to the docker config.

```
RUN git config --global url."git@gitlab.com:".insteadOf "https://gitlab.com/"
```

(That rather obscure error obfuscates the fact that it `go get` is having some more basic problems.)

Comment: The go authors are discouraging vendoring and plan to deprecate it, so its to something I am keen to branch into.

Comment: It's feasible to shield `vendor`, but this is a private warehouse. Before compilation, you need to configure git account or password in docker `$home /. Netrc `, or configure SSH certificate, or use `git config --global url."git@gitlab.com:".insteadOf "https://gitlab.com/"`, to convert git protocol, so as to ensure that go can get package through git during compilation

For more details, please refer to: https://golang.org/doc/faq#git_https

Comment: Yikes, I completely forgot I had done that global config change on this machine. Thank you kind stranger. 謝謝！ @Qi-Yin

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely missing something in your environment that is set up for you upon login. Go builds are affected by environment variables like `GOPATH` and `GOROOT`. Your gitlab repo might require ssh keys for access. It's something you would have had to set up at some point. Look in your `.bashrc` and `.profile` files, and the output of the `env` command for hints.

Comment: Yes and also `GOPRIVATE` and `GONOSUMDB`

Comment: `go env` is a good way to see all the go environment variables